# How to get user input values in VB console application?

Tags: vb.net

How to get the user input values in below code:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim url As String = "http://localhost:8080/"
    Using WebApp.Start(Of Startup)(url)
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green
        Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url)
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start sending events to connected clients")
        Console.ReadLine()
        Dim context As IHubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext(Of MyHub)()
        For x As Integer = 0 To 5
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)

            Console.WriteLine("Server Sending Value to Client X: " + x.ToString())
            context.Clients.All.addMessage(x.ToString())
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Using
End Sub
Public Class Startup
    Public Sub Configuration(ByVal app As IAppBuilder)
        Dim config = New HubConfiguration With {.EnableCrossDomain = True}
        app.MapHubs(config)
    End Sub
End Class
<HubName("myHub")> _
Public Class MyHub
    Inherits Hub
    Public Sub Chatter(param As String)
        Console.WriteLine(param)
        Clients.All.addMessage(param)
    End Sub
```

**CLIENT CODE**

```
Sub Main()
    Dim connection = New HubConnection("http://localhost:8080")

    Dim myHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("myHub")

    connection.Start().Wait()
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow
    myHub.Invoke(Of String)("Chatter", Console.ReadLine) _
    .ContinueWith(
        Sub(task)
            If task.IsFaulted Then
                Console.WriteLine("Could not Invoke the server method Chatter: {0}", _
                                  task.Exception.GetBaseException())
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("Success calling chatter method")

            End If
        End Sub)

    myHub.On(Of String)("addMessage", _
        Sub(param)
            Console.WriteLine("Client receiving value from server: {0}", param.ToString())
        End Sub)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

When I try to use the While loop I can't achieve the same where it exits once after it receives two input values.

**Changes i made** `myHub.On(Of String)("addMessage", _`

```
 Sub Main()
    Dim connection = New HubConnection("http://localhost:8080")

    Dim myHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("myHub")

    connection.Start().Wait()
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow
    myHub.Invoke(Of String)("Chatter", Console.ReadLine) _
    .ContinueWith(
        Sub(task)
            If task.IsFaulted Then
                Console.WriteLine("Could not Invoke the server method Chatter: {0}", _
                                  task.Exception.GetBaseException())
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("Success calling chatter method")
            End If
        End Sub)
    Dim input As String = Console.ReadLine()
    While input <> "Exit"
        Console.WriteLine("Server Sending Value to Client X: {0}", input)
        myHub.On(Of String)("addMessage", _
          Console.WriteLine("Enter a value to send to the Client.  Enter 'Exit' to quit")
        input = Console.ReadLine()
    End While

    '    myHub.On(Of String)("addMessage", _
    '        Sub(param)
    '            Console.WriteLine("Client receiving value from server: {0}", param.ToString())
    '        End Sub)
    '    Console.ReadLine()
    'End Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: What user input values?  Your question is not clear.

Comment: when the code is executed the server is sending the hardcoded messagesServer ' Sending Value to Client X:0' 5 times as i have given the condition For x as Integer = 0 to 5 and sleep for sometime when itry to input some values to send to client it exits

Comment: but i want to send whatever input values i  type once the code is executed

Comment: You need to store the input into a variable and then send that to the server:  `Dim input As String = Console.ReadLine()  context.Clients.All.addMessage(input)`

Comment: its behaving like chat application and this the server part i can send inputs from client and its received at at the server n number of times. but i can send the input only once from the server to the client once i sent the value from server to client it exits

Comment: That's not valid syntax for the `For` statement.  Also, `Console.ReadLine` only returns strings.  You cannot assign the result directly to an integer without first converting it.

Comment: hi Could you help me i'm not sure whats happening inside the .continuewith Sub(task) if else statement don't know hoe to send user inputs in sequence as in server code

Answer (score 1):

If you need to send multiple inputs to the server, try using a loop.  Something like this (untested):

```
Sub Main()
    Dim url As String = "http://localhost:8080/"
    Using WebApp.Start(Of Startup)(url)
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green
        Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url)
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start sending events to connected clients")
        Console.ReadLine()
        Dim context As IHubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext(Of MyHub)()

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a value to send to the server.  Enter 'Exit' to quit")

        Dim input As String = Console.ReadLine()
        While input <> "Exit"
            Console.WriteLine("Server Sending Value to Client X: {0}", input)
            context.Clients.All.addMessage(input)

            Console.WriteLine("Enter a value to send to the server.  Enter 'Exit' to quit")
            input = Console.ReadLine()
        End While
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank  you sooo much

Comment: Hii I have been using the below Client to interact with the server i tried using the same while loop to achieve the same but its becoming a infinite loop